# How a page is constructed and rendered in magento 1.9.1?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

I have couple of years of experience in IT and now I have started learning magento on my own. I have gone through some video tutorials for learning this tool.

But I have very basic question in my mind. Is there any link/document/article which describes in details how the page is constructed and displayed in the browser. I googled it and found one or two links but I didn't get satisfactory/detailed content on it. Can anybody help me in this regard?

Thanks all.

Comment: What do you mean by constructed? https://www.google.ch/search?q=How+does+magento+layout+work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch) to an article written by Alan Storm for Magento 1.12 which is in the Magento Knowledgebase.

It covers layouts, blocks, and templates which are also used in Magento 1.9